# Inset photo on iPhone 7 running iOS 10

Tags: photos, camera, ios, iphone

On a few occasions now, when viewing photos in the "Photos" app, I have seen a small inset photo appear in the top left corner of the screen.

Insets seem to be triggered by some sort of downward swipe gesture, but I don't know exactly what triggers insets. I also do not know how they are of any use.

Can anyone shed any light on how to produce this inset photo and why it is of use?

This is what I'm seeing - NOTE THIS IMAGE WAS DONE IN PHOTOSHOP
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Image posted. Note this image was done in Photoshop, but this is more or less what I see on iPhone

Comment: Just to be clear, your device is not jailbroken and these are still pictures (not videos)?

Comment: No device not jailbroken and they are still photos (although they are possibly "live photos".

Comment: Note inset photos seem to be triggered by some sort of downward swipe gesture

Comment: I just had the same thing happen but I thought it might have been an upwards gesture.